# file_put_content creates empty file

Tags: php, file, permissions, lighttpd, samba

I have connected my server to an smb share, where all web files are stored. I also have lighttpd as webserver. The network drive is mounted and can be read by lighttpd. But when I try to write a file with `file_put_content`, an empty file will be created. And there is also a warning in the error.log: "permission denied"

Where could be my mistake?

Comment: So file can be read, but do you have enough permissions to write, huh?

Comment: Let's see, i check this in the console...

Comment: No I dont have them. But i dont get where i must give the write permissions.  It's already mounted as file_mode=0777

Comment: The file is not accessible to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file is accessible to PHP (open_basedir). Here's what is probably causing the problem: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir